# Rounded corner on clip-path : polygon

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners, clip-path

I am experimenting with a navigation bar and currently using a **clip-path: polygon** for my links.
Ideally I would want to **round out** my **top-left corner**. I've been searching for a minute, but couldn't come up with anything that works. Any ideas?

**Code below:**

```css
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    background-color: #1A2434;
}
```

```html
<div class = "menu"></div>
```

Comment: I have reviewed every answer ,though it wasn't exactly what i wanted, cause so far I've only managed to round out the whole div, but I couldn't find a proper solution, to only round out my top left corner

Comment: why you dont use?
border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;

Comment: It doesn't work in the top left corner, only in the other corners, it was the first thing i tried

Answer (score 0):

I did come up with a solution ,which is not ideal, but it works :p

```html
<svg width="1440" height="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect fill="#000" x="104.99999" y="0" width="614.00001" height="150" id="svg_1" rx="55" stroke="#000"/>
  <rect fill="#000" x="150" width="1290" height="150" id="svg_8" stroke="#000"/>
  <path stroke="#000" id="svg_3" d="m0,150l118.68751,-131.00001l395.62505,0l118.68747,131.00001l-633.00002,0z" fill="#000"/>
 </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).